# Passing an array from android to phpmysql database

Tags: android, json

I have fetched data from mysql database from android and now through checkbox i want to submit the checked values into the database .How can it be done? I am new to android.Here is my code for fetching data

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    { String result = "";
        /*Intent intent =getIntent();
        String Courseno =intent.getStringExtra(Main3Activity.Courseno);
        textViewCourse.setText(Courseno); */
        String courseno = "CSE3202" ;
        String host = "http://192.168.0.105/fetch.php?course=CSE3202";
        try {URL url = new URL(host);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            result = convertStreamToString(in);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new String("Ther exception: " +e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{
            Log.d("ededed","ee"+result);
            JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
            int success =jsonResult.getInt("success");
            if(success==1)
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                JSONArray students = jsonResult.getJSONArray("Courseno");
                for (int i=0; i< students.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject student= students.getJSONObject(i);
                    Integer rollno = student.getInt("Rollno");
                  /*  String firstname =student.getString("firstname;");
                    String lastname =student.getString("lastname;");
                    String line = rollno + "-" + firstname + "-" + lastname; */
                    String line = rollno + "";
                    users.add(new UserModel(false, line));
                }
            }
```

Comment: `How can it be done` depends on how your server expects it

Comment: im using localhost

Comment: that has nothing to do with `how your server expects it`

Comment: in which format, and which way, which headers and which URL it expects you to send it the data

Comment: how could i understand that?

Comment: you (or somebody else) have implemented the server (in PHP as you told). Now you need to ask the guy who implemented it in which format should you send the data that the server understands it, and puts the update into the database. Probably nobody has implemented this part of server yet, so you will have to implement it

Comment: I want it in json format

Comment: 1) `phpmyamin` you had to mention it in the question. 2) As I said, `somebody else have implemented the server. Now you need to ask the guy who implemented it in which format should you send the data`, in case of PHPMyAdmin - check it's documentation on how to do that

Comment: can you plz help in this regard?providing sample code

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Since you were able to fetch the data just fine, what exactly is a problem for you to update it using the documentation?

Comment: i have done it by online help. In documentation it is  not specifically mentioned about the topic.